# Does Dijkstra work with all negative weights

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

Would Dijkstra work with all negative weights, considering the condition, that we choose the most negative value and go ahead with it? [Normal Dijkstra Algorithm]

I couldn't find the answer online.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to think about the intuition behind the algorithm. The reason why it fails for negative edges is because local min doesn't guarantee global min. If you have all negatives, however, local max guarantees global max, hence its correctness

Comment: No, Dijkstra doesn't work with negative weight, if you want to find a solution for that situation, `Bellman–Ford algorithm` is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the weights were negative and you chose the **least** negative weights that'd be isometric traditional Dijkstra's where weights are positive and the least positive weights are chosen, and hence would work fine. To say it another way, you'd want to pick the *maximum* weights (least negative).

Choosing the **most** negative weight is like choosing the most positive weight. It doesn't work since Dijkstra's is a minimization algorithm.

Dijkstra's also fails when you have a mix of positive and negative weights and the graph has cycles. If the goal were to maximize total weight then a cycle with negative weight would be fine, but one with positive weight would lead to an endless loop where the algorithm chooses to take the cycle over and over and over.